# How to Prevent Cloudflare Workers from running on ?ajax-wc

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, worker, cloudflare-workers

I have several cloudflare workers and understand how to create a Bypass.. however, you are not allowed to bypass on query urls such as "?ajac-wc". Simultaneously, running my workers on this url **breaks** my call to Ajax on Woocommerce... So for now, I have set my workers to run on every single letter of the alphabet like so (but there has to be a better way; no?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's currently no way to specify a negative route based on the presence of a query in the URL. You will have to design the worker itself such that it checks for the query and forwards the request on to origin verbatim if it is present.

Comment: To confirm, this actually will not work - and the reason is because ajax-wc is being “fetched” instead of loading as the main url. The main url remains /checkout.

Comment: I don't understand, why does that mean it won't work?

Comment: Is there a manner to check a "fetch" for a query? Because right now I have tried to check the url for a query, which of course does not work because that is not the main url. Do you have an idea how to incorporate this?

Comment: Each fetch will generate a new event on the Cloudflare Workers side. `request.url` for that event will be the full URL including the query.

Comment: Is there a downside to my method? Seems to work perfectly